# Node.js input password to a bin file being run via spawn

Tags: node.js, stdin, child-process

I am running a `.bin` file via `child_process.spawn()`, which takes in some inputs from the user before completing the setup. It seems to work fine taking all the inputs correctly via `process.stdin.write("input"\n);`. However, the same doesn't work when the password is sent via stdin. Directly running the `bin` file and manually entering the password works. Is there some format I am supposed to set before sending the password via node.js? I just keep seeing `*` being logged on stdout continuously and the setup doesn't seem to proceed further. Below is the snippet that I am using

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var process = child_process.spawn('./test.bin');

process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
if(data.toString().trim() === 'Username:')
    process.stdin.write("test\n"); // This works
else if (data.toString().trim() === 'Password:')
    process.stdin.write("password\n"); //This doesn't
```

Any inputs on the same might be helpful.Thanks.

Please note that when the password is entered by directly running the `bin` file, upon typing the password, nothing is displayed, but entering the correct password works. So, I am thinking there might be some encoding issues or something like that which I may be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seemed to work by entering the password string one character at a time like below:

```
process.stdin.write(password[0]);
process.stdin.write(password[1]);
process.stdin.write(password[2]);
process.stdin.write(password[3]);
process.stdin.write("\n");
```